# React Router will not redirect based on state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the code, it reaches the isRegistered function, I know this as I have it console.log state. The state of registered is equal to true. So therefore based on the code it should redirect to /login but it is not.

```js
import React from 'react'
import "./Register.css";
import {BrowserRouter as Route, Redirect, Link} from 'react-router-dom'
const initialUser = {
  username: "",
  email: "",
  password: "",
  password2: "",
  name: ""
}
class Register extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: initialUser,
      registered: ''
    };
  }

  onUsernameChange = event => {
    this.setState({ username: event.target.value });
  };
  onNameChange = event => {
    this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
  };

  onEmailChange = event => {
    this.setState({ email: event.target.value });
  };

  onPasswordChange = event => {
    this.setState({ password: event.target.value });
  };
  onPassword2Change = event => {
    this.setState({ password2: event.target.value });
  };
  isRegistered() {
    const { registered } = this.state;
    console.log(registered, 'here', this.state)
    if (registered) {
      return (
          <Redirect to='/login' />
      )
    }
  }
  onRegister = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/register", {
      method: "post",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: this.state.name,
        email: this.state.email,
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password,
        password2: this.state.password2
      })
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data.isRegistered);
      if (data.isRegistered) {
        this.setState({registered: true})
        this.isRegistered();
      }
    })
  };

  render() {
      return <div className="login-page">
          <div className="form">
            <form className="login-form">
              <input type="text" placeholder="name" onChange={this.onNameChange} />
              <input type="text" placeholder="username" onChange={this.onUsernameChange} />
              <input type="text" placeholder="email" onChange={this.onEmailChange} />
              <input type="password" placeholder="password" onChange={this.onPasswordChange} />
              <input type="password" placeholder="confirm password" onChange={this.onPassword2Change} />
              <button className="bluecolor" onClick={this.onRegister}>
                Register
              </button>
              <p className="message">
                Have an account? <a href="/login">Login</a>
              </p>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>;
  }
}

export default Register;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

It reaches all the way to the if statement in isRegistered(). So I assume it is the redirect component that is wrong but I cannot figure it out for the life of me.

//UPDATE
This is now what I have in it

```js
import React from 'react'
import "./Register.css";
import {BrowserRouter as Route, Redirect, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
const initialUser = {
  username: "",
  email: "",
  password: "",
  password2: "",
  name: ""
}
class Register extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: initialUser,
      registered: ''
    };
  }

  onUsernameChange = event => {
    this.setState({ username: event.target.value });
  };
  onNameChange = event => {
    this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
  };

  onEmailChange = event => {
    this.setState({ email: event.target.value });
  };

  onPasswordChange = event => {
    this.setState({ password: event.target.value });
  };
  onPassword2Change = event => {
    this.setState({ password2: event.target.value });
  };
  isRegistered() {
    const { registered } = this.state;
    console.log(registered, 'here', this.state)
    if (registered) {
      this.props.history.push('/login')
    }
}
  onRegister = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/register", {
      method: "post",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: this.state.name,
        email: this.state.email,
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password,
        password2: this.state.password2
      })
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data.isRegistered);
      if (data.isRegistered) {
        this.setState({registered: true})
        this.isRegistered();
      }
    })
  };

  render() {
      return <div className="login-page">
          <div className="form">
            <form className="login-form">
              <input type="text" placeholder="name" onChange={this.onNameChange} />
              <input type="text" placeholder="username" onChange={this.onUsernameChange} />
              <input type="text" placeholder="email" onChange={this.onEmailChange} />
              <input type="password" placeholder="password" onChange={this.onPasswordChange} />
              <input type="password" placeholder="confirm password" onChange={this.onPassword2Change} />
              <button className="bluecolor" onClick={this.onRegister}>
                Register
              </button>
              <p className="message">
                Have an account? <a href="/login">Login</a>
              </p>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>;
  }
}

export default withRouter(Register);
```

And this is the main App.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import RegisterFull from "./Components/Register/RegisterFull";
import LoginFull from "./Components/Login/LoginFull";
import HomeFull from "./Components/Home/HomeFull";
import FullContact from "./Components/Contact/FullContact";
import './App.css';
import './Components/flex.css'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from "react-router-dom";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      signedIn: false
    }
  }
  loginUser = () => {
    this.setState({signedIn: true})
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
        <Route exact={true} path='/' component={HomeFull}/>
        <Route path='/contact' component={FullContact} />
        <Route path='/login' component={LoginFull} />
        <Route path='/register' component={RegisterFull} />
        <Route path='/about' component={HomeFull} />        
        </div>
      </Router>
      
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar my thought process behind this was simply that once they are registered, then they should be redirected to the login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some improvements in your code you could make. Here is my suggestion. `you don't need to bind anything`. You are using latest `React`. How I know? You are doing `onUsernameChange = evnet => {}` not `onUsernameChange(event){}`. Overall @Sakhi Mansoor is right.

```js
import React from "react";
import "./Register.css";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Route,
  withRouter,
  Redirect,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

const initialUser = {
  username: "",
  email: "",
  password: "",
  password2: "",
  name: ""
};

class Register extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: initialUser,
      registered: ""
    };
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      user: {
        ...this.state.user,
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
      }
    });
  };

  isRegistered = () => {
    const { registered } = this.state;
    console.log(registered, "here", this.state);
    if (registered) {
      this.props.history.push("/login");
    }
  };

  onRegister = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/register", {
      method: "post",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(this.state.user)
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data.isRegistered);
        if (data.isRegistered) {
          this.setState({ registered: true });
          this.isRegistered();
        }
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="login-page">
        <div className="form">
          <form className="login-form" onSubmit={this.onRegister}>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="name"
              name="name"
              value={this.state.user.name}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="username"
              name="username"
              value={this.state.user.username}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="email"
              name="email"
              value={this.state.user.email}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <input
              type="password"
              placeholder="password"
              name="password"
              value={this.state.user.password}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <input
              type="password"
              placeholder="confirm password"
              name="password2"
              value={this.state.user.password2}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <button className="bluecolor" type="submit">
              Register
            </button>
            <p className="message">
              Have an account? <a href="/login">Login</a>
            </p>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Register);
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot return `Redirect` element in render like this by invoking another method in component lifecycles or methods.

You need to wrap your component with `withRouter` HOC which provides history props.

```
import {BrowserRouter as Route,, withRouter, Redirect, Link} from 'react-router-dom'


export default withRouter(Register);
```

and if you want to navigate programmatically :

```
isRegistered = () => {
const { registered } = this.state;
console.log(registered, 'here', this.state)
if (registered) {
 this.props.history.push('/login)
 }
}
```

Comment: I did the suggested edits as you said and yet I still do not get redirected. Is there something I need to do to the main App.js?

Comment: What error did you get ? Make sure your method gets invoked and where is your router implementation

Comment: That's the thing, there are no errors, I am not getting redirected. I know it is reaching the function as the console.log is working properly which shows that this.state.registered is equal to true, which in turn should make your code run, however I do not get redirected.

Comment: I believe you forgot to bind your method. This is undefined in this method

Comment: Is your issue fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how to redirect on a button click.Hope this might help you

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter,Route,Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Sample}/>
      <Route path="/test" exact render={()=>(<p>Test</p>)}/>
      </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}
class Sample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.Click = this.Click.bind(this) // you need to bind the method
  }
  Click() {
    this.props.history.push('/test');
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <button onClick={this.Click}>Click</button>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: using this, for some reason it would show the login page for just a second then revert back to the register page.